# Set PayPal Direct Payment errors language

Tags: paypal

Is there any way to set the language of the errors returned by PayPal when processing a Direct Payment API call?

I've tried with:

```
LOCALECODE=es_US
```

to show them in spanish, but no luck. I called PayPal Support and the person said he didn't know, that I should ask in the forums ?!?!?

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal is not going to return the error message back in the selected language for the buyer.  If you are wanting language specific errors, you would need to create your own database.  Then based on the country, and the error number that is returned you can display the correct error message in that particular language.

Answer (score -1):

You are probably looking for [this](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/support) , or at least I think that the person to whom you were talking was suggesting this kind of approach.

Remember that you are handling moneys and payments here, if you are not sure about what are you doing spend some months/years to refine your approach.

Comment: Hey, this question has nothing to do with how to create a payment system, I am sure of what I'm doing (I've already implemented the payment system and works great), I'm asking a simple translation question